# Extract string from a path

Tags: shell-script

Problem statement: I want to extract an unknown string(last string) from a given path name in a single line command.

Restrictions:

1. The path is dynamic and can change with users input.
2. Only last string is to be extracted using only one line o command.

Sample:

Eg1:

```
/home/xyz/Desktop/tools
```

In this case, I need to just extract the word `tools`.

Eg2:

```
/tmp/my_directory/my_big_dir/my_small/dir/cross
```

In this again, I need to extact the last string `cross`

Is there a way to do this?

I tried to use `cut` command but it didn't work as the path length is dynamic.

Comment: What shell? at least in bash, you can do `"${str##*/}"` to remove the longest prefix matching `*/` from `str`. Or use `basename`.

Comment: I don't want to traverse to the directory and execute the the command. I want to extract the last string without traversing.

Comment: @steeldriver, `${parameter##word}` is in all POSIX shells, (not just `bash`, see `man dash ksh` etc.).

Comment: @AbhimanyuSaharan, suppose `p=/home/xyz/Desktop/tools`, run `x="${p##*/}"` to set _$x_ to "tools", and `echo $x` to print "tools".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `basename` is the command you are looking for.

```
[me@host ~]# basename /home/xyz/Desktop/tools
tools
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that in bash and other shells without calling another program, which is of course much faster:

```
$ x=/home/xyz/Desktop/tools
$ echo ${x##*/}
tools
$ y=/tmp/my_directory/my_big_dir/my_small/dir/cross
$ echo ${y##*/}
cross
```

The `##` removes the longest prefix it can find matching `*/`

Comment: If you happen to have a path with a trailing slash (e.g. `/foo/bar/`), this will eat through to the final slash and return nothing. `basename` on the other hand seems to return the final component, i.e. `bar`

Comment: I don't believe this is in POSIX, either, so if you're on some crappy platform where all you have is the plain-Jane Bourne shell (e.g. [Debian unless you use a bash shebang](https://wiki.debian.org/DashAsBinSh)), it won't work.

Comment: @Kevin, Don't worry, it works in dash too. Even if it didn't, I suppose you did notice that the /bin/sh symlink can be changed.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Fair enough, but changing the symlink is [using global state to manage a local problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081211-00/?p=19873).  The correct solution is to set an appropriate shebang line.

Comment: @ilkkachu If the string has an (optional) ending `/`, then use: `y=${y%/}; echo ${y##*/}`

Answer (score 0):

```
basename /your/full/path
```

Gives you the output that you want: path